# Using Named Mutex

Tags: c#, mutex

I have two instances running of same Windows Service. They check the health of each other and report if any issue is found. I have a critical job that needs to be performed so I am running it with a fail-over approach, it runs in Master, and if Master is not responding it runs in slave. This job needs to communicate over a specific serial port, I am trying to use Mutex to check for race condition. I dont have access to production, so before deploying I want to make sure my approach is fine. So please suggest if my use of Mutex is fine for the given case.

```
if (iAmRunningInSlave)
{
   HealthClient hc = new HealthClient();
   if (!hc.CheckHealthOfMaster())
      return this.runJobWrapper(withMutex, iAmRunningInSlave);
   else
      return true; //master is ok, we dont need to run the job in slave
}
return this.runJobWrapper(withMutex, iAmRunningInSlave);
```

And then in runJobWrapper

```
bool runJobWrapper(bool withMutex, bool iAmRunningInSlave)
{
   if (!withMutex)
      return this.runJob(iAmRunningInSlave); //the job might be interested to know 
   Mutex mutex = null;
   string mutexName = this.jobCategory + "-" + this.jobTitle; //this will be unique for given job
   try
   {
      mutex = Mutex.OpenExisting(mutexName);
      return false; //mutex is with peer, return false which will re-trigger slave
   }
   catch
   {
      try
      { //mean time mutex might have created, so wrapping in try/catch
         mutex = new Mutex(true /*initiallyOwned*/, mutexName);
         return this.runJob(iAmRunningInSlave); //the job might be interested to know where I am running
      }
      finally
      {
         if (null!=mutex) mutex.ReleaseMutex();
      }
      return false;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had a similar issue recently.

The design of the `Mutex` class is a bit weird/different from the normal classes in .NET.

Using `OpenMutex` to check for an existing `Mutex` is not really nice as you have to catch an exception.

A better approach is to use the

```
Mutex(bool initiallyOwned, string name, out bool createdNew)
```

constructor, and check the value returned by `createdNew`.

Comment: There is TryOpenExisting method.

Comment: It appeared in .NET 4.5.

Answer (score 0):

You don't look to check the return value from `runJobWrapper` anywhere - is this intentional? It is not obvious what the return value actually means anyway. Also you really shouldn't catch each any every exception that `OpenExisiting` could possibly throw - Out of memory? Stack overflow? etc. etc. Just catch the one you mean to handle correctly.

Also your code looks to be somewhat fragile - I wouldn't be surprised if you have race conditions.

Comment: the first portion was hand written scalled down variant...i missed it...has edited the question

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that mutex.ReleaseMutex() was not releasing the mutex immediately..I had to call GC.Collect()

Comment: Careful about your expectations, the .NET GC is not deterministic

Comment: mutex.ReleaseMutex() is not Dispose()! It does not release the resources held by the mutex, but it "unlocks" the mutex so other process can acquire it via Mutex.WaitOne(). For disposing the Mutex use mutex.Close(). Please read the documentation.