# Thread synchronization based on value

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, mutex, critical-section

I'm trying to synchronize threads in a critical section, but I need to do it based on a value.
For example if you have threads doing work representing different people (ie bob, fred, bill) then the threads for Bob and Bill could be concurrent, but all of Bob's threads would be synchronized so that only 1 can go through the critical section at a time. My initial thoughts are to use named mutex, but not sure how to manage them. Perhaps some type of dictionary of named mutexes. Has anyone done something similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- If you have a `Person` class representing the person (Bob, Bill, etc.), you can `lock` on that instance.
- If you do not have a class representing a `Person`, create a `Dictionary` that maps unique identifiers of your people to instances of named `Mutex` objects. The access to the dictionary itself should be synchronized. Also note that mutex creation in .NET is non-trivial. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/847270/335858) for details.

Answer (score 4):

Typically, in such scenarios, you will have a single `User` instance for each user.

If so, you can just `lock()` on that user instance.

Comment: @jsp, like SLaks says, use `lock` on the current user, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz(v=vs.110).aspx